# Login issue with Restassured api testing

Tags: api, rest-assured

I tried to generate the token from login request.It is successful in postman tool and success in soapui groovy script.But I couldnot do via rest assured library.Below are the screenshot where the request uses Body - form-data with username and password.
[image]

I have tried the using queryparams, formparam but getting the below error.Kindly help me to solve the error.

```html
    <html>
    <head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
    <center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
    <hr><center>nginx/1.4.4</center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Rest assured code:

```java
    Map<String, String> formParams = new HashMap<>();
            formParams.put("username", "test");
            formParams.put("password", "welcome");

            Response response = RestAssured.given().config(RestAssured.config().redirect(redirectConfig().followRedirects(false)).encoderConfig(EncoderConfig.encoderConfig().encodeContentTypeAs("multipart/form-data", ContentType.TEXT)))
                .queryParams(formParams)
                .post("http://posturl");
```

Comment: Post your rest-assured code please - without that it is hard to help.

Comment: Hi Kenny , I have appended the code

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the parameters as a query, not as form params.

Also, looks like you need to follow the redirect, since you're getting a `301`, so you need `followRedirects(true)` instead of `false`.

You need to do it this way:

```java
Response response = RestAssured.given()
                .config(RestAssured.config()
                        .redirect(new RedirectConfig().followRedirects(true))
                        .encoderConfig(EncoderConfig
                                .encoderConfig()
                                .encodeContentTypeAs("multipart/form-data", ContentType.TEXT)))
                .formParams(formParams)
                .post("http://posturl");
```

Comment: Thanks Kenny for your response , I tried the same and even now it throws the same error.Kindly help me more

Comment: Updated. Please change `followRedirects` to `true`.

Comment: Thanks Kenny , let me try when the server is up and then I will notify here.

Comment: I tried with followRedirects to true still the same error.Kindly help

Comment: Made another change, as not sure what `redirectConfig()` was doing, so I updated to create a new `RedirectConfig` object. Try that.

Comment: Still the same error after updating.Is there any other settings to do.I did the same in python request library and able to get the response.

Comment: What version of restassured are you using?